# How to remove brownies cleanly from silicone molds?

Tags: baking, brownies

I've recently started looking into making brownies inside silicone molds (in particular, [this guy](https://www.amazon.de/gp/product/B018VG38H6/ref=oh_aui_detailpage_o01_s00?ie=UTF8&psc=1)) and I've noticed that it doesn't seem to matter whether I grease, grease & flour, use pam, use parchment paper (with and without grease) or do nothing: the brownies are never guaranteed to come out cleanly. Each method yields some brownies that cleanly separate, with others that lose varying degrees of their bottoms to the pan.

Note: with parchment paper, the problem of a clean release just gets kicked down the road to the stage when I peel the paper off the brownie. Most of the time, the paper pulls a non-trivial amount of crumb off with it.

What's the best way to insure a perfect removal of the brownies from silicon bakeware?

Answer (score 2):

Freeze the brownies in the mold. They'll release cleanly.

Answer (score 1):

I'd try parchment paper. Seems to usually be a good idea even when oil and flour fail. You'll have to cut it to size, but at least the sheets are big enough that it shouldn't be too much hassle.

You can cut it larger than the pan in one direction so that it'll be sticking up on two sides, which gives you something to grab to lift out and to peel off the brownies. For the pan you linked, divided into a grid, you could cut it to size in one direction, lay it across a row, maybe put a few creases to encourage it to go down into the sections, then quickly snip it into individual pieces.

Comment: Tried parchment paper, see edit.

Comment: @StevieP technically, this does what you ask... If your recipe is so sticky that it won't come cleanly off of parchment, you might want to consider a different recipe or be ok with the rough release if you really love the flavor of this one. I've never had significant issues with brownies releasing from pans. They usually have plenty of oil to release cleanly.

Comment: What can we add to the recipe to make it less sticky?

Comment: Recipe design is complicated. It may be that it is not stickiness, but excessive crumbliness, or something else. Trying a few different recipes is much less work than changing this one to perform differently.

Comment: You can try greasing or flouring the paper too. I suspect it still won't be enough, but the paper should be less sticky than the silicone, so the combination of the two night make some difference. You might also check that you're baking the brownies the right amount (being off might make them more crumbly?) or trying other recipes if all else fails.

Answer (score 0):

A reach but take cup cake paper and cut it in an rectangle and put it in the bottom.  Now it may also stick to the paper but you could cut with a knife.